# Echo certain value from an array

Tags: php

I am trying to echo a certain value of an array which  was outputted by an API call.

So when i call

```
$userid = 42
$api->listServersByOwner($userid)
```

will output

```
Array ( [success] => 1 [errors] => Array ( ) [data] => Array ( [Servers] => Array ( [259] => user42 Server ) ) )
```

What i specifically want is to put the "259" in a variable.

Please do note that this number changes allot depending on the userid so it wont always be 259.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean

```
$array = $api->listServersByOwner($userid);
$var = key( $array['data']['Servers'] );
```

Comment: But lets say for this array

Comment: array(
    'success' => true,
    'errors' => array(),
    'data' => array(
        'status' => 'online',
        'onlinePlayers' => '1',
        'players' => array(
            0 => array(
                'ip' => '192.168.1.149',
                'id' => '12',
                'name' => 'Player'
            )
        )
        'maxPlayers' => '16'
    )
)

Comment: How can i get the onlineplayers?=

Comment: Then you just get the value, not the key

$var = $array['data']['onlinePlayers'];

Answer (score 0):

Replace $arr with the name of your variable.

```
echo key( $arr['Servers'] );
```